# Which is the right way to know type of the argument passed to the generic method in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, generics, reflection

From my `C# 4.0` code, I want to execute some queries on `Sybase` and `MSSQL`. The database being used (or to be used) will be decided/known **at runtime** only.

I am using `AseCommand` and `SqlCommand` for Sybase and SQL respectively.

I decided to create generic method like this:

```
private Department ExecuteCommand<T>(T databaseCommand) where T : class
{
            Department department = new Department ();

            dynamic command = databaseCommand;

            using (dynamic databaseReader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (databaseReader.HasRows)
                {

                    while (databaseReader.Read())
                    {
                         department.Employees.Add(this.CreateDepartmentInstance(databaseReader));
                    }
                }
            }

            command.Connection.Dispose();

            return department;
        }
```

**Questions:**

1. Is there better option other than `dynamic`?
2. What is usually **the right way to know the type of the argument passed to the generic method**?
3. Of course, I can write two separate methods for Sybase and SQL. But why to do so when something like `dynamic` is at disposal?

Comment: Here's a handy rule of thumb: If you need to know the type of a generic argument, then generics is probably the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @spender - I would +100 that comment if I could!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You do not necessarily need dynamic here, all you require is a common interface (which in this instance they both have):

```
private Department ExecuteCommand<T>(T databaseCommand) where T : IDbCommand
```

However, in this instance since you are not doing anything particularly interesting with type `T` (as far as I can see), the following method signature would suffice:

```
private Department ExecuteCommand(IDbCommand databaseCommand)
```

In general, if there is no common interface, I'd recommend using the facade pattern and simply delegating method calls through to equivalents on the actual implementation.

Comment: ...or, less confusingly `ExecuteCommand(IDbCommand databaseCommand)`

Comment: @rich.okelly : I completely missed `IDbCommand`. I did not notice both of them implement `IDbCommand`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `AseCommand` and `SqlCommand` both implement `IDbCommand`, so you just need to change the type constraint:

```
private Department ExecuteCommand<T>(T databaseCommand) where T : IDbCommand
{
    Department department = new Department();

    using (IDataReader databaseReader = databaseCommand.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (databaseReader.HasRows)
        {

            while (databaseReader.Read())
            {
                department.Employees.Add(
                                 this.CreateDepartmentInstance(databaseReader));
            }
        }
    }

    command.Connection.Dispose();

    return department;
}
```

I Imagine you'd also need to change `CreateDepartmentInstance` to accept an `IDataReader` if it doesn't already.

Though as rich.okelly points out, it doesn't look like there's really a reason to use generics here in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to #2:

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(object) ) {
    // Check for IEnumerable
}
```

Replace object with whatever type you would like to check for.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, using a common interface will do just fine.

In general, if you want to find out the type of an object you can always use the `is` and `as`-Operators.

```
private Department ExecuteCommand<T>(T databaseCommand) where T : class
{
            Department department = new Department ();

            var command = databaseCommand;

            using (var databaseReader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if ((databaseReader as IDataReader).HasRows)
                {

                    while ((databaseReader as IDataReader).Read())
                    {
                          department.Employees.Add(this.CreateDepartmentInstance(databaseReader));
                    }
                }
            }

            command.Connection.Dispose();

            return department;
        }
```

Not verified in VS, but it should work.